# how to write the following code using Left join instead of using *= operator?

Tags: sql-server-2008

the code is :

```
IsNull(QPSAbs.SlabID,0) *= Slabdet.SlabID
```

here they have used `*=` operator to indicate left join which is not supported in recent versions on MS SQL . So suggest me a code which is appropriate for the updated version

Comment: You should poste more of your query. Especially the part starting with `FROM`...

Answer (score 0):

This is - probably... - somthing like

```
[...]
FROM QPSAbs
LEFT JOIN Slabdet ON QPSAbs.SlabID=Slabdet.SlabID
```

This would return all rows of QPSAbs, even if there is no detail data in Slabdet and the related Slabdet rows...